# how can i set incoming webhook from gitlab to a messenger(not slack, not famous one)?

Tags: gitlab, webhooks

I want to set incoming webhook from gitlab when someone commented on issues to a messenger.
Of course, the messenger supports getting incoming and outgoing webhooks.

But the messenger is not a famous one like Slack.
I googled how to get incoming webhook messages but they all explained about slack. There should be a way of setting this kind of webhook.
I read the [documents](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) but I didn't understand what to do.

On this page, for example : https://mygitlab_address/mygroup/someproject/hooks

What could I input on the 'URL'?  Should I write a script and upload to a server and input the script's URL? If I do, what kind of script should I write on the script?

I have no idea at all.
Could anyone help me get through this?
Anything would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Does your messenger support incoming webhooks?

For example, here is Slack's documentation: https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks

Does your messenger have something like that?

If so, you'll be configuring GitLab to call to your messenger's incoming webhook.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, still, I cannot figure out the way. T_T For example, in number 4 in the slack's doc, where should I write the codes and what kind of file format is that?